# Bing Maps - MapShapeLayer on top of map children

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-runtime, bing-maps

I'm using **Bing Maps SDK** on **Windows 8.1 Store App** (WinRT, XAML, C#)

Children added to the map component are always on top on the items added in the ShapeLayers collection of the map.

Is there a way to modify the "*Z-Index*" for the MapShapeLayer in Bing Maps in a way that they appear on top of some children ?

**Here is an exemple :**

*XAML :*

```
<bing:Map x:Name="bingMap">
    <bing:Map.Children>
        <bing:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItems}">
            <bing:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    ...
                </DataTemplate>
            </bing:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </bing:MapItemsControl>
    </bing:Map.Children>
</bing:Map>
```

*C#*

```
this.bingMap.ShapeLayers.Add(mapShapeLayer);
```

The MapItemsControl will be on top of the mapShapeLayer but I want the opposite. Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. If shapes appeared above the children you would not be able to interact with the children. The children property is normally used for adding custom pushpins or controls to the map, most of which are meant to be interactive to the user.